# Maintaining the state in load balanced server?

Tags: load, state, load-balancing

What are the ways to mainatain the state in load balanced servers?

I am using one application which is hosted in two different servers. Now I want to check a record about whether it has already been taken by somebody to edit or not.

How to maintain a state inorder to accomplish my above requirement.

Comment: Which web platform are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share session state when using ASP.NET then you either need to use a StateServer or SqlServer to store session state.

The StateServer is a service built into Windows that takes serialized objects and allows the servers to query the data out. The Sql operation does a similar thing, but stores them in a database rather than in memory somewhere.

More information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx)